# How to fix "If one image has no bands, the other must also have no bands"

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to divide every image to 10000 then change the negative values in every pixels of a image to zero from (2015-01-01) to (2016-12-30) but when I am trying to run this code
it gives me this error:

> If one image has no bands, the other must also have no bands.

How can I fix this error?

```
var year = 2015;
var fromDayOfYear = 1;
var toDayOfYear = 730;

var collection  = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MYD13A1')
  .select('EVI');
  
var list = ee.List([]);

function addAODLayer(image, dayOfYear) {

  var new_img = image.clip(table);
  
  list = list.add(new_img);
  
}

function sequence(start, end) {
  return Array
    .apply(null, {length: 1 + end - start })
    .map(function (_, i) { return i + start });
} 
  
sequence(fromDayOfYear, toDayOfYear) // Client side array
  .map(function (dayOfYear) {
    var date = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 1, 2).advance(dayOfYear - 3, 'days');
    var value = 0
    var image1 = collection
      .filter(ee.Filter.date(date.getRange('day')))
      .mean()
      .divide(10000)
    var image2 = image1.lt(0)
    var image = image2.multiply(value).add(image1.multiply(image2.not()));
    addAODLayer(image, dayOfYear);
  });
  

var new_col = ee.ImageCollection(list);

var AOD = new_col.mean();

var AODVisParam = {
  min: 0,
  max: 1,
  palette: ['ffffff', 'ce7e45', 'df923d', 'f1b555', 'fcd163', '99b718', '74a901',
    '66a000', '529400', '3e8601', '207401', '056201', '004c00', '023b01',
    '012e01', '011d01', '011301'],
};

Map.addLayer(AOD, AODVisParam, 'AOD');
Map.centerObject(table);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will stick to your statement

> I want to divide every image to 10000 then change the negative values in every pixels of a image to zero from (2015-01-01) to (2016-12-30)

1. Your sequence is daily, but the collection contains an image every 16 days, so when you map over the sequence you get an empty collection in almost all days (except every 16 days). This is the line that is giving you the error:

```
collection.filter(ee.Filter.date(date.getRange('day')))
```

2. the way you're trying to get your results doesn't make much sense to me, this:

```
var image = image2.multiply(value).add(image1.multiply(image2.not()));
```

since the `var value = 0` then the first parts is an image full of zeros. Then you add the "real" result you need, but this is not how I'd do it.

This is how I'd code it to get the result for your statement

```
var start = "2015-01-01"
var end = "2016-12-30"

var collection  = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MYD13A1').select('EVI')
                    .filterDate(start, end);
                    
var new_col = collection.map(function(img){
  var negative = img.lt(0)
  var final = img.divide(1e4).where(negative, 0)
  return final
})

var AOD = new_col.mean();

var AODVisParam = {
  min: 0,
  max: 1,
  palette: ['ffffff', 'ce7e45', 'df923d', 'f1b555', 'fcd163', '99b718', '74a901',
    '66a000', '529400', '3e8601', '207401', '056201', '004c00', '023b01',
    '012e01', '011d01', '011301'],
};

Map.addLayer(AOD, AODVisParam, 'AOD');
```

You can clip in the mapping function if needed.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/247a410c7ad6b00b110def9f518730fc